# Creating dictionary for multiple dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

Trying to create a dictionary that contains multiple dictionaries, so that I can add data to the data key to each dictionary later.

Code so far:

```
decisions = ['decision1', 'decision2','decision3']
id_number = ['a1','a2','a3']

for x, y in zip(decisions, id_number):
    decision = {"name": x, "ID": y, "data": pd.DataFrame()}
    globals()[x] = decision
```

So far, this just creates multiple dictionaries. But I want to be able to put it into one dictionary so that I can use a for loop and input data into the `data` key within each dictionary.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: What's your expected output? Is there any reason why you're using `globals()` as opposed to a dictionary?

Comment: What would the dict structure be like? Presumably a nested dict with the inner dict as shown in your code and an outer dict keyed on `x` (i.e. `descision1` etc)?

Comment: You already _do_ put it in one dictionary, the one returned by `globals()`. To put it in a different dict, replace `globals()` with the name of your target dict

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's a little confusing to understand your exact requirements but assuming you want to use the values from `id_number` as your keys in the top level dictionary you can do something like:

```py
decisions = ['decision1', 'decision2','decision3']
id_number = ['a1','a2','a3']

main_dict = {}

for x, y in zip(decisions, id_number):
    decision = {"name": x, "ID": y, "data": pd.DataFrame()}
    main_dict[x] = decision
```

functionally this is almost the same as your code except it is not creating a bunch of variables in the global namespace.

if you wanted to trim this down you can do:

```py
decisions = ['decision1', 'decision2','decision3']
id_number = ['a1','a2','a3']
main_dict = {x: {"name": x, "ID": y, "data": pd.DataFrame()} for x, y in zip(id_number, decisions)}
```

Comment: Apologies for the confusion in my question, but you managed to decipher it and answer correctly. I appreciate it~